# Implementation of dispersion compensation of lamb waves

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, python, acoustics, software-implementation

I am trying to implement the method from Paul Wilcox [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TUFFC.2003.1197965) "A rapid signal processing technique to remove the effect of dispersion from guided wave signals" on data from a lamb wave propagating in a plate (I have the dispersion curves of the plate, and can assume that I only look at A0 mode).

The signal I am working with has 501 samples, with a sample rate of 500kHz; the pulse has a center frequency of 15kHz. So it is very oversampled.

He has split the method up into steps.

> - Pad the received time-trace, g(t), with zeros to yield a time domain signal containing a number of points that is an integral power of two
>   and at least eight times as many as in the original signal.
> - Perform an FFT on the zero-padded time-domain signal to obtain G(ω).
> - Calculate the number of points, n, in the wavenumber domain, the size of the wavenumber step, ∆k, and the size of the distance step,
>   ∆x, in the final distance-trace using the rules given in (12), (10),
>   and (11), respectively.
> - Interpolate G(ω) to find its value, G(k), at points equally spaced in k for the desired mode.
> - Calculate the group velocity of the guided wave mode at the same wavenumber points, vgr(k).
> - Compute H(k) = G(k)vgr(k).
> - Apply an inverse FFT to H(k) to obtain the dispersion compensated    distance-trace h(x).

I struggle to understand how to calculate ∆k, ∆x, and the new k array with equally spaced points.

I have managed to get some results by just inserting them into the formulas from the paper:
$$(5): dω = vgr(ω)dk, ω = vph(ω)k$$
$$(9): n∆x>m∆t v_max.$$
$$(11): k_{Nyq} \geq k(f_{Nuq})$$
$$k_{Nyq} \geq k(1/(2\Delta t))$$
$$\frac{1}{2\Delta x} \geq k(1/(2\Delta t))$$
$$\Delta x \leq \frac{1}{2k(1/2\Delta t)}$$
$$(10): \Delta k = \frac{1}{n\Delta x} < \frac{1}{m \Delta t v_{max}}$$
$$(12): n > 2\frac{k_{Nyq}}{\Delta k}$$
Using this gives a reasonably compensated signal, but I don't know how to get the correct distance axis.
What I would like my end result to be is a dispersion-compensated signal with a spatial resolution of 1mm and an axis from 0 to 1m (as the maximum wave travel length is around 0.6m). Also using a lower Nyquist frequency seems reasonable, but I am unsure of the effects of just lowering f_nyq.
For example, this is how the new k array looks compared to the calculated k array, if I use the original fs and f_nyq.
[image]
If I change f_nyq to 60kHz I would assume that it would be similar but I get this:
[image]
I assume that there is something wrong with my implementation, or is it okay that the new k array does not match up with the calculated one?

To summarize:

- I would like some explanation on the wavenumber domain and its
  effect, and how the calculations of dk, dx, and new k are done.
- What I have to do if I would like to specify the max distance and the
  spatial resolution.
- What I have to be careful of when lowering the f_nyq.

Here is the code I am using for now if that is interesting.

```
def dispersion_compensation_Wilcox(file_n=2, postion=5, fs=500000):
    """
    Performs dispersion compensation on the input signal.

    Args:
        signal (ndarray): The input time-domain signal.
        postion (int): The postion we want to use.
    fs (int): Samplerate

    Returns:
        ndarray: The dispersion compensated distance-trace.
    
    """


    def get_k_value(freq):
        v_freq = get_velocity_at_freq(freq)['A0']['phase_velocity'] #fetches the velocity at the upper frequency
        k_freq = (2*np.pi*freq)/v_freq
        return k_freq

    wave_data_top, x_pos_top, y_pos_top, z_pos_top, time_axis_top = get_comsol_data(9) #fetches data from comsol files
    wave_data_bottom, x_pos_bottom, y_pos_bottom, z_pos_bottom, time_axis_bottom = get_comsol_data(10) #fetches data from comsol files
    signal = (wave_data_top[postion]+wave_data_bottom[postion])/2 #A0 mode
    n_times = 16 #number of points that is an integral power of two and at least eight times as many as in the original signal.
    m = len(signal)
    n_fft = 2 ** int(np.ceil(np.log2(n_times * m)))
    signal_padded = np.pad(signal, (0, n_fft - m), mode='constant')
    #computing fft of padded signal
    G_w = np.fft.fft(signal_padded)
    dt = 1/fs # 1/500000
    freq_vel = np.fft.fftfreq(G_w.size, dt)
    G_w = G_w[freq_vel>0]
    freq_vel = freq_vel[freq_vel>0]
    f_nyq = fs/2
    v_gr, v_ph = wp.theoretical_group_phase_vel(freq_vel, material='LDPE_tonni20mm', plot=True) #group and phase velocity with the same length as freq_vel
    k = (2*np.pi*freq_vel)/v_ph #same length as freq_vel. Wavenumber domain 
    v_nyq = get_velocity_at_freq(f_nyq)['A0']['phase_velocity'] #fetches the velocity at the nyquist frequency
    v_max = np.max(v_gr)
    k_nyq = get_k_value(f_nyq)
    dx = 1/(2*k_nyq)
    print(f'dx: {dx}')
    dk = 1/(n_fft*dx)
    k_max = k[-1] #doesnt matter if i use this or this 2*np.pi*upper_freq/v_max since both are equal or 2 times k_nyq
    print(f'k_nyq: {k_nyq}, kmax: {k_max}')
    w = 2*np.pi*freq_vel
    print(f'shape of w: {w.shape}')
    n = len(k)
    print(f'length of k: {n}')
   

    k_new = np.arange(0, k_max + dk, dk)
    
    x = np.arange(0, n_fft * dx, dx)
   
    # Interpolate G(w) to find G(k)
    G_interp = interpolate.interp1d(k, G_w, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=0)(k_new)

    v_gr_interp = interpolate.interp1d(k, v_gr, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=0)(k_new)


    # Compute H(k) = G(k) * vgr(k)
    H_k = G_interp * v_gr_interp

    # Apply inverse FFT to H(k) to obtain the dispersion compensated distance-trace
    h_x = np.fft.ifft(H_k)
    print(f'shape of h_x: {h_x.shape} before removing zero-padding')
    # Remove zero-padding from the compensated signal
    h_x = h_x[:m]
    x = np.arange(len(h_x))*dx
    #normalize h_x and signal
    h_x = h_x/np.max(h_x)
   
    return h_x.real
```

Comment: Are you solve the problem finally? Can you share the final code? Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In order to help you I need you to expand the functions:

- `get_velocity_at_freq()`,
- `wp.theoretical_group_phase_vel()`

that are not detailed in your code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Signal Processing SE. Please note that this is a Q&A site and **not** a forum, so please refrain from posting comments as answers. I understand that you don’t enough “reputation” yet to leave comments on other people’s posts, but if you get involved just a little bit (answer a couple of questions, post another, etc.) this “privilege” will be acquired quite fast. Until then, please do not post comments as answers as they will most probably deleted.